# Como eliminar "\" en python?

Tags: python, micropython

Mi codigo lee de un archivo txt lo siguiente: b'\x00\x13\xa2\x00A\xeaVa'
lo cual esta en string pero lo necesito tal cual en bytes, al momento de pasarlo a bytes me arroja esto: b"b'\x00\x13\xa2\x00A\xeaVa'", la parte de b"" ya lo logre quitar con la funcion replace pero las dobles diagonales "\" todavia no, ya que si lo agrego a replace se me eliminan las dos y solo necesito eliminar una, alguna solucion? gracias

```
while True:
mac = []
text = open("macgw.txt", "r")
macy = text.read()
characters = ""

for x in range(len(characters)):
    macy = macy.replace(characters[x],"")

arrMac = bytes(macy, 'utf-8')
print(arrMac)'
```

la salida me da: b'\x00\x13\xa2\x00A\xeaVa'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si realmente el fichero contiene la cadena `b'\x00\x13\xa2\x00A\xeaVa'` tal cual, la solución más simple sería:

```
with open("macgw.txt", "r") as f:
   contenido = f.read()
macy = eval(contenido)
```

Pues `eval()` ya se ocupa de evaluar esa cadena y por tanto generar un string de bytes.

### Nota sobre seguridad

**CUIDADO**. Como te puedes imaginar `eval()` es potencialmente peligroso, pues es capaz de ejecutar cualquier código python que le pases como cadena (bueno, no cualquier cosa, por ejemplo no puede ejecutar un `import`, ni una asignación, sino solo expresiones, lo que mitiga un poco su peligrosidad, pero aún así... permite llamadas a funciones por ejemplo)

Una alternativa menos peligrosa sería la siguiente, pero no la propuse inicialmente porque no estoy seguro de si estará soportada por micropython:

```
import ast
with open("macgw.txt", "r") as f:
   contenido = f.read()
macy = ast.literal_eval(contenido)
```

En este caso, en vez de `eval`, uso `ast.literal_eval()`. Esta función sólo puede evaluar correctamente lo que sean "literales", es decir, datos, pero no expresiones más complejas ni comandos.

Demostración de que funcionaría en tu caso:

```
import ast

ejemplo_cadena = r"b'\x00\x13\xa2\x00A\xeaVa'"
como_bytes = ast.literal_eval(ejemplo_cadena)
print(type(como_bytes))  # --> <class 'bytes'>
print(como_bytes.hex())  # --> 0013a20041ea5661
print([hex(b) for b in como_bytes])
#  --> ['0x0', '0x13', '0xa2', '0x0', '0x41', '0xea', '0x56', '0x61']
```

### Extra

Pero cabe preguntarse ¿por qué el fichero contiene eso? ¿Has generado tú ese fichero? En ese caso me temo que el problema fue que al escribir en él lo abriste en modo texto en lugar de modo bytes, y por tanto el `.write()` convirtió en cadena lo que tendrían que haber sido bytes.

Es decir, si hubieras generado el fichero así:

```
with open("macgw.txt", "wb") as f:
   f.write(tus_bytes)
```

Entonces podrías haberlo leido en la forma siguiente y ahorrarte todos estos problemas:

```
with open("macgw.txt", "rb") as f:
   macy = f.read()
```

(el modo `"wb"` escribe bytes, en vez de cadenas, y el modo `"rb"` los lee)

Comment: Estaría bueno que adviertas sobre los peligros de ejecutar código arbitrario de Python desde una cadena.

Comment: @DanteS. Tienes toda la razón. Arreglado.

Comment: Un problema con la última alternativa ("rb") es que el pedazo a convertir puede ser sólo parte del archivo leido. Por ejemplo, cuando lees un código fuente.

Comment: Sí, por eso había pedido yo algunas clarificaciones en comentarios. Veremos si el OP confirma si esto le vale.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que el archivo con el texto está codificado en UTF-8, una solución es:

```
with open("texto.txt", "r") as archivo:
    linea = archivo.readline().strip()
    octetos = bytes(linea[2:-1], "ascii").decode("unicode-escape")
    print("Bytes: ")
    for oct in octetos:
        print(f"{ord(oct):02x}", oct)
```

Lo central es

```
    octetos = bytes(linea[2:-1], "utf-8").decode("unicode-escape")
```

Lo primero es deshacernos del "b'" inicial y de la comilla final, para lo cual usamos `linea[2:-1]`.

La función `bytes()` toma un cadena y lo convierte en una secuencia de bytes. El segundo argumento es la codificación usada para crear esa cadena. Normalmente es "UTF-8" en el mundo Python, pero podría ser "ASCII" o alguna otra si viene de sistema pre-unicode. El resultado intermedio es

```
b"\\x00\\x13\\xa2\\x00A\\xeaVa"
```

Ahora queda *interpretar* el contenido, ya que los cinco caracteres en "\x00" representan en realidad un solo valor entero entre 0 y 255. Para interpretar el contenido usamos `.decode("unicode-escape")`

El resultado es un string donde cada caracter tiene el valor del byte original. Para recuperar el valor del byte, usas la función `ord()`.

#### Demo

```
with open("texto.txt", "r") as archivo:
    linea = archivo.readline().strip()
    octetos = bytes(linea[2:-1], "ascii").decode("unicode-escape")
    print("Bytes: ")
    for oct in octetos:
        print(f"{ord(oct):02x}", oct)
```

produce:

```
Bytes: 
00  
13 
a2 ¢
00  
41 A
ea ê
56 V
61 a

Process finished with exit code 0
```